# step$anova following stepAIC() not subsettable?

Tags: r

I'm trying to run a simple backwards stepwise multiple linear regression in R using the stepAIC function from the MASS package. The model runs fine, but I can't seem to get the results. When I run "step$anova" I get

```
Error in step$anova : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

I've used this exact code many times and never gotten this error before, but I also see no issues in my data matrix or any difference between this and what I usually do. Any tips on this error would be greatly appreciated.

My code is:

```
PCBiomass<-lm(y1~x1+x2+x3,data=abioY1)
PCBstep<- stepAIC(PCBiomass, direction="backward")
step$anova
```

the data are attached and useable (earlier in the code they're used in an RDA)

Comment: You are using the variable `step` but you never created a variable `step`. (The `$` is an operator on that variable.)

Comment: *facepalm* it's the always the little things!!! Lesson learned: don't copy/paste code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops, It should be `PCBstep$anova` in the final line. You can not subset `step`, because that is an R's built-in function. *(You know the `stats::step` function, right?)* A function is a closure; that is what the error is complaining about.